# Pearson Correlation for Clustered data

Tags: correlation, spss, sampling

I have a sample that was drawn using cluster sampling. Let say I have variables x and y, and I would like to check the significance of correlation between those two variables in SPSS 20 taking into account cluster sampling.

The problem is that SPSS "complex  samples" dialog doesn't offer such an option. Would it be correct to define sampling plan (with "Complex Sampling" ->  "Prepare for analysis") and use Complex Sample GLM to estimate simple model y = x + e with this sampling plan and then check if coefficient for x variable is significant?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Complex Samples, but your solution will work with any survey analysis software. To test the correlation, fit the model:

$$
E(Y|X) = \alpha + \beta X
$$

and test the significance of the $\beta$ term. The survey program will generate a standard error for $\hat{\beta}$ which is "design-based". Tests and confidence intervals for $\beta$  will be valid ("robust") in situations where there are non-normal errors or non-constant variance.

However before you do any testing,  you should plot the data and check for non-linearity in the association between $Y$ and $X$, just as you would do for ordinary (non-survey) regression.

The program will likely report an estimated $R^2$, and you can use the square root $R$  as the estimate of the correlation.